# Highcharts - Why is column so narrow on datetime axis?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm creating a Highcharts datetime column chart, with the ability to switch between three time intervals: day, week, and month. I'm having some success, but keep getting hung up on one piece. When there is only one column for the month time timeinterval, the column is too narrow. I have tried adjusting the pointWidth and pointRange options with little success.

```
chart.options.plotOptions.column.pointRange
chart.options.plotOptions.column.pointWidth
```

How can assign a width to the single column?

Please see the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ricksuggs/PRKAJ/ and try clicking the Monthly button after the chart has loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the maxZoom xAxis.
Try to change the value.

`maxZoom: null`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PRKAJ/31/)

Hope that solved you problem solved.